# Find the sum of the values of $x$ where the vertical asymptotes of $f(g(x))$ are located.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, fractions

If
$$f(x) = \frac{2x-8}{x^2 -2x - 3} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad g(x) = \frac{3x+9}{2x-4}$$
find the sum of the values of $x$ where the vertical asymptotes of $f(g(x))$ are located.

---

After expanding , I got : $ 4 ( x^2 - 7x + 10 )/(3x^2 - 20x - 21 )$ , but I am not so sure how to go forward.

Comment: I am not sure that the expansion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical asymptotes are located in points where your function will tend to $\infty$ (denominator tends to $0$, and then depends on the numerator, I let you do the work, you just have to find the points where the polynomials are null)